# How to get all folded lines from StyledText

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, code-folding

In my eclipse plugin, I have a `StyledText` object and `IEditorReference` object. I also have a yCoordinate that I want to use to check which line number is below this coordinate:

```
        int lineIndex = styledText.getLineIndex(yCoordinate);
```

This works fine, if there is no line folding applied. Therefore I'm looking for a method that takes either line folding into account, or that gives me back all the folded lines so that I can manually adjust the `lineIndex`. What are my options?

Answer (score 2):

From the `IEditorReference` you can get the `IEditorPart`

```
IEditorPart part = ref.getEditor(false);
```

If the part is an `ITextEditor` you can do the following:

```
ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor)part;

IDocumentProvider provider = editor.getDocumentProvider();

IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();

IDocument document = provider.getDocument(input);

int line = document.getLineOfOffset(offset in text);
```

'offset in text' is the number of characters from the start of the document. `StyledText` has a number of methods to get this value, for example `getOffsetAtLocation(Point)`.

Comment: Hmm that looks good, but what do you mean by "offset in text"?